¿porque la funcion solo toma la primera fila de una tabla y no la fila seleccionada en un combobox tkinter python?
Hola soy principiante y Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación de escritorio Python Tkinter, pero la función para setear los datos solo toma la última fila de una tabla sqlite y NO la seleccionada en
el Combobox/ComboboxSelected donde está cargada la tabla o consulta. Gracias de antemano
def consulta_productos():
    conexion = sqlite3.connect("baseDatos1.db")
    cursor = conexion.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT codigo, descripcion, uMedida FROM productos")
    resultado = cursor.fetchall()
    conexion.commit


def seleccionCombobox(a):
    listado = consulta_productos()
    for i in listado:
        codigo.set(i[0])
        descripcion.set(i[1])
        uMedida.set(i[2])

consulta_prod = Label(ventana, text="Consulta")
consulta_prod.place(x=50, y=10)
listado = ttk.Combobox(ventana, width=50, state="readonly") 
listado["value"] = consulta_productos()
listado.place(x=130, y=10)
listado.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", seleccionCombobox)


Estás iterando sobre el listado en vez de obtener el valor actual del listado.

Te agradezco Excorpion...

Al hacer:
listado = consulta_productos()
for i in listado:
    codigo.set(i[0])
    descripcion.set(i[1])
    uMedida.set(i[2])

estás iterando sobre todas la filas de la tabla, al final del ciclo codigo, descripcion y uMedida tendrán el valor correspondiente de la última fila. Es lo mismo que si haces algo como:
listado = [
    [1, "Producto 1", 14],
    [2, "Producto 2", 74], 
    [3, "Producto 3", 17]
]

for producto in listado:
    codigo = producto[0]
    descripcion = producto[1]
    uMedida = producto[2]
    
print(f"Codigo: {codigo}, descripcion: {descripcion}, uMedida: {uMedida}")
# Imprimirá: "Codigo: 3, descripcion: Producto 3, uMedida: 17"

Para implementar tu idea tendrías que obtener el indice del item seleccionado en el combobox y usarlo para indizar sobre la lista retornada por consulta_productos().
Ten en cuenta que la callback recibe como argumento el evento que a ocasionado su llamada, ese evento es el parámetro al que llamas a en tu callback y que no usas para nada. Puedes obtener el widget responsable del evento usando su atributo widget, el cual será una referencia a tu combobox en este caso.
Con la referencia al combobox puedes usar el método get() para obtener la selección actual y el método current() para obtener el indice de esa selección, por lo que podrías hacer algo como:
def seleccion_combobox(event):
    index = event.widget.current()
    cod, desc, umed = consulta_productos()[index]
    
    codigo.set(cod)
    descripcion.set(desc)
    uMedida.set(umed)

Aunque dado que estableces como valores del combobox  la fila completa de la consulta, no necesitas llamar de nuevo a consulta_productos(), simplemente:
def seleccion_combobox(event):
    cod, desc, umed = event.widget["values"][event.widget.current()]
    codigo.set(cod)
    descripcion.set(desc)
    uMedida.set(umed) 


Excelente!!! te agradezco FJSevilla
